# a prolom when run command from prolog use shell

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

i have a problem with executing commands in prolog,

as http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=shell/2

i am trying to run a python file from prolog using the shell

```
shell('cmd.exe /C python C:\\Users\\yousef_soliman\\a.py').
```

but it returns in prolog

> false

i have installed python and i can run it from the cmd

```
python C:\\Users\\yousef_soliman\\a.py
```

and it works

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
shell('python C:\\Users\\yousef_soliman\\a.py').
```

Comment: false again @Roberto